# No pruedo crear ngFor desde un XML o XLS

Tags: xml, angular5

estoy tratando de leer un xml con Angular 7 la idea es lograr después pasarlo a una tabla cuando logre obtenerlo  el componente es :

```
 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'; 
  export class AppComponent {
  title = 'exel';

  dataString=null;
  Data=null
  DataNN=null


  onFileChange(ev) {
    let workBook = null;
    let jsonData = null;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const data = reader.result;
      workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
        const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
        initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        return initial;
      }, {});
      this.dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

      this.Data = this.dataString.slice();

    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    console.log(this.dataString)
  }

 ejecutar(){ 
 console.log(this.Data)
  this.DataNN=this.Data

   }
```

> el HTML es

```
 <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />

  <div id="output"></div>
   <br>
   <div >
    <button class="btn-primary"  (click)="ejecutar()" > Download JSON File 
  </button>
  </div>

  <li *ngFor="let item of DataNN">
    {{item.id}}

  </li>
```

> y me da un error asi:
>
> > ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"Hoja1":   [{"id":411615883,"Peso":284},{"id":411400820,"Peso":326},
> >     {"id":365244833,"Peso":278},{"id":365244754,"Peso":616},
> >     {"id":411400874,"Peso":366}]}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports
> >     binding to    Iterables such as Arrays. at
> >
> > > 

Comment: DataNN es un string JSON, tienes que parsearlo para obtener el array

Comment: Perfecto Pablo Lozano , pero¿ como lo parseo?

Comment: igual que antes has hecho el camino inverso, transformarndo un objeto en JSON con `JSON.stringify(...)`, ahora puedes hacer `JSON.parse(this.DataNN)`. De hecho, no sé para qué necesitas hacer la primera transformación...

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a  Pablo Lozano y investigando un poco lo puede realizar les dejo el codigo por si alguno lo necesita desde ya gracias TOTALESSSS...

```
 ejecutar(){ 
 const data = JSON.parse(this.Data);
 this.DataNN=data.EVENTOS;
 console.log(data.EVENTOS)
   console.log(this.DataNN);
}
```

EVENTOS:es el nombre de la pagina del archivo exel por default es Hoja1